# Google Maps fails to load in Chrome

Tags: google-maps

.  ,        '      .            .

---

When I visit Google Maps in the Google Chrome browser, all I see is a blank grid for the "Map" mode. The "Satellite" mode works fine.

I don't see this issue in Firefox and Edge. Why does Google's own browser have this bug, and how can I fix it?

I've been having this issue for several months.

Comment: Whew. Good thing this question has 2 answers. I'm safe from auto-deletion, yay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit [`maps.google.com`](http://maps.google.com) in the [latest chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/)

If you ever see a blank map grid, it could be because of a bugged cookie Google left in your browser.
[How to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/335912/how-to-fix-blank-google-maps-in-chrome/) recommends you to just delete the cookies and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open google map in secure website... or you can search google map on google then open first website. it helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "you have to open google map in secure website"?  Do you mean HTTPS?  This is very unclear at present.